# Accessing properties of "this" during bind

Tags: javascript, binding

Learning partial functions and got stuck with this query -

In the code snippet below, I create an admin object that re-uses a generic sendMail function by customizing it with a bind (partial function). However when this runs the `from` parameter to `sendMail` is always received as `undefined`.

If I replace `sendMail: sendMail.bind(this, this.role)` with `sendMail: sendMail.bind(this, 'admin')` it works fine.

How do I get the `sendMail` binding inside the `admin` object to pass variables defined inside the `admin` object?

```
function sendMail(from, to, content) {
    console.log(`Sending email from ${from} to ${to} with message as ${content}`);
}

let admin = {
    role: `admin`,
    sendMail: sendMail.bind(this, this.role),
}
admin.sendMail(`all`, `Reboot in 15 mins`);
```

Comment: In an object initializer (like the value for `admin`) the value of `this` is **not** a reference to the "under construction" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you'll have to separate out the assignment to the "sendMail" property:

```
let admin = {
    role: `admin`,
};
admin.sendMail = sendMail.bind(admin, admin.role);
```

There's no way to reference the "under construction" object in the property value expressions in an object initializer. While that's being evaluated, *there is no object yet* (at least conceptually).